# Using fields defined by Constructor Shorthand in Field Initializer

Tags: typescript, tsc, ts-node, typescript-class

I'm currently having issues after compiling my code to JS which do not happen when running the same code in ts-node.

Assuming following code :

```
class A {
  constructor(readonly parameterProperty: number) {}
  readonly fieldInitializer = this.parameterProperty * 10;
}
```

It seems that ts-node first initializes the parameterProperty, then initializes the field with the already created value.
The compiled JS code however first tries to initialize the field, then the parameterProperty.
Compiled JS:

```
"use strict";
class A {
    parameterProperty;
    constructor(parameterProperty) {
        this.parameterProperty = parameterProperty;
    }
    fieldInitializer = this.parameterProperty * 10;
}
```

I'm wondering if this means using parameterProperties in this fashion is not intended. Sadly I was not able to find anything about the initialization order of these in the Docs.

TSconfig wise I am using :

```
 "target": "ES2022",                         
 "module": "CommonJS",
 "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
 "experimentalDecorators": true,
 "esModuleInterop":true,
```

I've actually found a solution to getting the compiled code behave just as when beeing run with ts-node.
Since I spend a few hours searching I want to document this here anyways though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, following result after searching and playing around in the TS-Playground.

Following setting changes the behaviour of the initialization order.

```
"useDefineForClassFields": false
```

Code beeing emitted with this disabled is:

```
"use strict";
class A {
    constructor(parameterProperty) {
        this.parameterProperty = parameterProperty;
        this.fieldInitializer = this.parameterProperty * 10;
    }
}
```

With this enabled the code looks like this:

```
"use strict";
class A {
    parameterProperty;
    constructor(parameterProperty) {
        this.parameterProperty = parameterProperty;
    }
    fieldInitializer = this.parameterProperty * 10;
}
```

Which thus changes the initialization order to first initialize the fields, then the parameterProperties.

Apparently this setting is true by default.

Comment: *"Apparently this setting is true by default."* Only if you have `target: ES2022` or higher, or `target: ESNext` (which is not the default), see [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#useDefineForClassFields).